# How do I mark a method as "afterwards, parameter X cannot be null"?

Tags: java, nullable, findbugs, notnull

I have this method:

```
 @Override
 public void foo( @Nullable Bar bar ) {
     Validate.notNull( bar, "bar is null" );
     bar.x();
 }
```

Since the method is defined elsewhere, I can't mark `bar` with `@NotNull`. The call to `Validate.notNull()` will make sure that `bar` isn't null but of course FindBugs and similar tools don't know anything about this constraint.

Is there a simple way to teach FindBugs that, after the call to `Validate.notNull()`, `bar` must be not null?

With simple, I mean a way where I have to define this in one place; of course, I could sprinkle my code with millions of `@SuppressWarnings`... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Change Validate.notNull to return the reference, marking its return value as `@NotNull`:

```
@NotNull
public static <T> T notNull(@Nullable T reference, String message) {
    if (reference == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException(message);
    }
    return reference;
}
```

Then use the result of the notNull call instead of the original parameter value:

```
public void foo(@Nullable Bar bar) {
    bar = Validate.notNull(bar, "bar is null");
    bar.x();
}
```